# How to prevent Google adsense invalid impressions while performing admin tasks on my wordpress site?

Tags: wp-admin, ads, adsense

I've added google adsense to my website. Currently I've got pretty less traffic (~3-30 visitors everyday).

I'm afraid that if I use my wordpress admin panel / write a post / view a post etc then it will create invalid ad impressions.

Google's policy on this is pretty vague and states the following:

> Can I view my own site without generating invalid impressions?
>
> Yes, you're welcome to view your own pages without generating invalid
>   impressions. Simply viewing your pages yourself will not jeopardize
>   your good standing in the AdSense program - however, please continue
>   to avoid clicking on any ads, and don't reload your pages excessively.
>   We take the issue of invalid clicks and page impressions very
>   seriously

It says that viewing your pages will not jeopardize your good standing. However, it goes on to forbid reloading pages "excessively". Since some days I get only 3-4 visitors there is a pretty good chance that I'll be making more number of page requests than actual users.

How can I avoid invalid ad impressions on my Wordpress site considering I would like to have ads on my site?

Comment: One solution would be using ad-block, I am using uBlockOrigin, and make settings to not pull ad from custom sites. You can custom uBlockOrigin filter

Answer (score -1):

The advertisements are only displayed on the Front-end of your site (whatever the visitors see). Since the ads are only displayed on the front-end, you don't have to worry about generating invalid impressions by reloading your admin page, creating posts, etc.

So long as you don't open your website's front-end area and start reloading like crazy, and clicking ads that you shouldn't, nothing will happen.